# Identify this Screw

Tags: wood, screws, drawers

[image: Screw]

What is the name/type of this screw?

This screw is used in this manual for assembly of my chest drawer.
Here is an excerpt from my assembly manual. Its usage is marked with "F".

[image: Assembly manual]

Comment: This is probably a specialty item from the company that makes the chest of drawers.  you can probably contact them if you need replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a screw designed with several components to meet several functions, one of which is to make it easy for anyone to build the object.

I have never seen it given a particular name, but several of the cheap furniture manufacturers use it.

A cam-lock screw may be applicable...

Comment: This screw seems similar to IKEA Cam Lock Screw #118331 from this [link](https://www.furnitureparts.com/collections/ikea-cam-lock-screws)

Comment: If you have an ikea item and need a replacement screw, just go in and ask, they have all sorts of tidbits.